# Why use the perfective "остаться" on one hand and the imperfective "оставаться" on the other?

Tags: грамматика

> Woman: Я могла бы **остаться** здесь навсегда.
>
> Man: Так **оставайся**.

I wonder why you need to use the perfective "остаться" on one hand and the imperfective "оставаться" on the other, even though they both refer to the same action of the woman staying in the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning

> Я могла бы остаться здесь **на**всегда.

**Imperfective verbs** can't go together with the adverb **навсегда**. They do with the adverb **всегда**, because the 1st denotes a momentary manner of action and the 2nd a continuous/incomplete one. So one can say

> Я могла бы оста**ВА**ться здесь ()всегда.

I believe it's useful to think of **навсегда** as `from this point onwards` and of **всегда** as `always`. And since **навсегда** implies a starting point, the verb it's associated with must be *perfective*, because these denote  an action which has either started or ended, where a putative fixed point in time is evident.

Concerning politeness, which is true, in this dialogue **останься** could possibly work as well because the interlocutors seem to be close acquaintances, which allows for more informal address. Perfective imperative also sounds somewhat more persistent and demanding and in informal setting the degree of imperative is up to the speaker.

Comment: Hi. Do you pronounce "бы остаться" like "**бо**статься" like a liaison in French?

Comment: @alone-Zee hi, it's ponounced **быастацца**, if instead of **бы** its shortened form **б** is used, then the pronunciation looks like **маглап астацца**

Comment: @alone-Zee There is no French-style liaison in Russian.

Comment: @alone-Zee some people may voice unvoiced consonants before words starting with a vowel and it's not unthinkable to have the shortened **б** pronounced like **маглаБастацца**, but vowels at final position don't get merged with the following word, if there's **бы** this **Ы** must be articulated... **б(ы)** itself is [**enclitic**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) which in Russian connect with the preceding word, that's why **маглап астацца** is more natural, and **маглабы астацца** accordingly

Comment: Hi. Regarding "навсегда" and "всегда": Interestingly, the same nuance applies to "**auf** ewig" and "ewig" in German. :)

Answer (score 6):

Imperfective imperatives (проходите, садитесь) sound more polite than perfective (пройдите, сядьте).